# creating a table interface in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

How can I create an interface similar like the following in Java (tweetie)?

[image]

I was thinking of using a JTable with one columns and customized cell that has an image in it...not sure how to do it though.

Comment: I would probably create a "speech-bubble" and use a `GridBagLayout` to position images and bubbles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way (I would do it) would be to use a Vertical [`BoxLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) on a `JPanel`.  Each tweet would then be its own `JPanel` (`TweetPanel extends JPanel`) with a [`BorderLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) where the image is on the WEST, and the tweet text is in the CENTER.

The following is how I would go about laying out one of the restaurant panels.

```
public ResturantPanel extends JPanel {

    public ResturantPanel(String name, String address, List<String> reviews, Icon icon){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel iconLabel = new JLabel(theIcon);
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel(name);
        JLabel addressLabel = new JLabel(address);
        JPanel southReviewPanel = new JPanel();
        southReviewPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(southReviewPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        for (String review: reviews) {
            southReviewPanel.add(new JTextArea(review));
        }
        add(southReviewPanel);
        add(iconLabel, BorderLayout.West);
        JPanel northPane = new JPanel();
        northPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(northPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        northPane.add(nameLabel);
        northPane.add(addressLabel);
        add(northPane, BorderLayout.North);
    }
}
```

Note, this was written entirely in this editor window.  It will have some typos.  Also, you will have to play with the sizing of the icon, the text areas added to the `southReviewPanel`, and `southReviewPanel` to get everything how you want it to look.

You would then place a bunch of these on a `JPanel` in a `JScrollPane`, and you are good to go.

Comment: I've choosed answers for my previously asked questions...if you don't mind helping now

Comment: @Equinox. Wow, good work!  What do you need more clarification on?

Comment: well.. I am actually not doing a twitter client. I have a list of restaurant names, address, reviews, and icons that I want to show in that one cell.. All I want is a format which has the icon on the left, restaurant name and details on the panel next to the icon

Comment: @EquinoX, I may have some tonight to take a look at a possible solution.

Comment: @EquinoX, see my edits, and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I actually did create something like you have coded above, however, what I really want is, say for the example above, Gizmodo should be a restaurant name and below that I want the address... the way you have it now is as a label for restaurant

Comment: @EquinoX, if you change the Layout of the `northPane` like I did above, it will layout the restaurant name above the address.

Comment: how can I have a margin between the icon and the box layout to the right?

Comment: @EquinoX, you can use the `setHgap` and `setVgap` methods of `BorderLayout` to play with gaps between the components.

Comment: @EquinoX, another option would be to change how you do the west panel.  Instead of directly adding the Icon, you can create a JPanel with the Icon and a spacer JPanel on it.  ANd then add the composite JPanel to the West.

Comment: Another question would be, how can I have multiple rows? I am guessing that I just need to keep adding the RestaurantPanel into a JFrame? Or Should I use something else besides a JFrame if I want it all to be in one column?I tried doing that and the layout is messed up. If there was a way to set the size of each RestaurantPanel to a fixed and unresizeable size... maybe that would work?

Comment: @EquinoX In order to show multiple rows of ResturantPanels you will want to add them to a `JPanel` with a `BoxLayout` on the `Y_AXIS`. and that `JPanel` will need to be within a `JScrollPane` if you want to be able to scroll through a bunch of restaurant reviews.

Comment: My only problem right now is that after putting everything as you said above.. if I resize the window size.. the layout becomes so messy because everything, including the RestaurantPanel gets resized. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: @EquinoX You should read up on how all of the layout managers you are using.  They specify how all of the components will be resized.  You should start by ensuring that a single restaurant panel resizes correctly.

Comment: the one that resizes is the southReviewPanel, which is a BoxLayout.. I just read the documentation on BoxLayout... and find no clue on how to make it resize correctly... some help?

Comment: @EquinoX, For starters, try adding it to the `South` of the border layout.  I'll try to throw something together.

Answer (score 3):

If you are only going to have one column, than you can just use `JList` and it will be a little easier. But to answer your question, you need to [create a cell renderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) that can be used to represent the object in the list. The renderer would have a method (`getListCellRendererComponent`) which would return a `Component` that can be used to represent each item.